# What is this little narrow leaved rosette forming plant?

Tags: identification, plant-health, houseplants

I have a little plant and don't know it's name. I don't know how to maintain it or what kind of soil or fertilizer it needs. Any suggestion is welcomed in advance!

**Edit1**: Can I bring out the root, and take a picture of it. IMO, If I know it is a **taproot** or **fibrous**, It might help in maintenance and the soil it needs. is it right?

[image: left]
[image: top]
[image: right]

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a member of the [Sansevieria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sansevieria) family, possibly a cultivar of [Sansevieria 'Hahnii'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sansevieria_%27Hahnii%27).  I realize the foliage shown in [these pictures](http://www.google.ca/images?q=sanseveria%20hahnia) is darker with stripes but as the Wikipedia article says

> There is great variation in foliage form within the genus.

When raised in low light it stretches out and the foliage becomes a lighter green.

Here are some cultivation suggestions from the [Sansevieria society](http://www.sansevieria-international.org/cultivation.htm)

> Sansevierias are succulent plants and so need a well-drained compost
>   and moderate watering. In the summer months they can be watered
>   frequently and appreciate this, as long as the soil does not remain
>   water-logged, but in the cooler months they are best left dry. A
>   minimum winter temperature of 10°C is recommended. Short periods of
>   lower temperatures may however be tolerated as long as the plants are
>   dry.
>
> Sansevierias will grow in many positions but appreciate good light and
>   dappled sun to grow naturally and produce good leaf shape and
>   colouration. Long green leaves, often produced in low light
>   situations, and admired my some collectors and growers, are not normal
>   and the leaves tend to be weak and featureless.
>
> The soil used for Sansevierias can be adapted to suit whatever
>   materials are available locally. The main constituent needs to be a
>   material which anchors the plant in the ground but at the same time
>   keeps the compost open to allow for excess water to drain through
>   quickly. This could be pumice or lava or any other neutral material.
>   To this needs to be added in about equal proportions some kind of
>   material containing humus and fertilizer. Again almost anything will
>   be suitable, peat or coir based composts or even orchid composts with
>   a slow release fertilizer added.

Edit: if the existing soil retains moisture too well you can just re pot with a better draining mixture.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, as you mentioned about moderate watering, I will reduce the water but how about soil? can I change the soil to be sure it is well-drained?

Comment: Maybe a sansiveria, but wouldnt be my first guess.

Answer (score 3):

Monocots are very tough to identify out of context... You could start by looking through the various genera in Asparagaceae and Liliaceae.

You will know better if it flowers...

Comment: thanks a lot I'm gonna search about Asparagaceae and Liliaceae.

Comment: Also if there is anything like a bulb attached to the foliage  (Liliaceae) or just root mass (could be Sansevieria).